# JQUERY $.post form to PHP script

Tags: jquery

As always thanks in advance if you're taking the time to take a look at this for me.

I'm struggling to post the form data to the php script. Currently the input field #userreviewtitle works perfectly however the textarea #comment and the option selection #hearts seem to not post. They will alert with through the jquery so the script is picking them up but just not simply posting.

What am I doing wrong here? Keen to work this out and to learn!

Here is the form:

```
    <div id="userreviewcontainer">

    <form id="userreview" name="userreview" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="userreviewtitle" name="userreviewtitle" placeholder="Review title">
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="4" placeholder="What is your opinion of <?php the_title(); ?>?"></textarea>
    <div id="userreviewrating">
    <select name="hearts" id="hearts">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Your Rating</option>
    <option  value="1">1 Heart</option>
    <option value="2">2 Hearts</option>
    <option value="3">3 Hearts</option>
    <option value="4">4 Hearts</option>
    <option value="5">5 Hearts</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="userreviewratingsubmit">   
    <?php if($_SESSION['login'] !== 1 || $_SESSION['logged_in'] !== "logged") {?>
    <a rel="prettyPhoto" href="#user_inline" class="button customreviewbutton">Submit</a>
   <?php }

    else if($_SESSION['login'] === 1 || $_SESSION['logged_in'] === "logged"){ ?>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="performreview" class="button customreviewbutton" alt="Submit"/>
    <?php } ?>


    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){



                $("#performreview").on('click',function(event) {
                //Create Variables
                var title = $('#userreviewtitle').val();
                var comment = $('#comment').val();
                var hearts =  $('#hearts').val();
                // Prevent form from submitting the normal way
                $("#userreviewnew").empty(); 

                $.post( "/wp-content/themes/xxxxxxx/process-comment.php", 
                {
                'userreviewtitle' : title,
                'comment' : comment,
                'hearts' : hearts
                },
                function( data ) {
                $('#userreviewnew').append(data);});

                event.preventDefault();
                });
});
</script>
```

Once again many thanks if you can point me in the right direction here

Comment: Have you tried just serializing the form data directly?  $("#userreview").serialize() (in place of your json string).

Comment: Sorry @jeff-ancel, You may have to explain that a little further. I'm still trying to learn Jquery. - In place of your json string?

Comment: I think he meant your data object. you don't have a json string.

Comment: Can you elaborate please @kevin-b ?

Answer (score 0):

What the two commenters are saying is that you're performing an extra and unnecessary step by collecting all of the form values and passing them into the Ajax call.

The better way is to use the jQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. Your code will look something like this (note that I prefer the `$.ajax` syntax but it should still be easy to follow):

```
$('form').on('submit'), function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(result) {
      $('userreviewnew').append(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
     console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing with the session status, but the important part is the line in the `$.ajax` call that begins with `data`. Please update if you're still not getting the expected values after making this mod.